# allow certbot validation and github action connection to digitalocean network firewall

Tags: digital-ocean, firewall, digital-ocean-apps

I have this digitalocean droplet that I served as staging instance and has network firewall on it. As it is a staging instance I made it work like a private access only by adding our outline vpn ip on http and https port, everything is working except when validating website with certbot and github action not able to connect to the droplet instance. How do I whitelist the github and certbot? Any help, suggestions, recommendations is greatly appreciated!